# How can I automatically add dashes in between PIDKEY entered by a user in Windows Installer?

Tags: windows-installer

Is it possible just using Windows Installer native functions, or should I use some kind of a custom action?

PS. I'm using Edit control to get PIDKEY not MaskedEdit control.

Comment: I don't think it's possible by Windows Installer out of the box - you have to write a custom action

Comment: So, you've already identified the `MaskedEdit` control as a way to do this. Why are you not using it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Um... it may be a matter of preference... :) I want just one edit control in the dialog for getting pidkey like MS Office 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the MaskedEdit control is if you have XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX it'll take 4 copy and paste operations as the control won't allow you to paste the entire property.

The behavior you see in Office 2010 isn't native to Windows Installer.  They are using an external UI handler and therefore are not bound by the limited, ancient controls offered by native Windows Installer.

Microsoft can rewrite the UI experience because they have lots of $$$ and this is a flagship product.   Does the same apply to you?  If not, keep it simple or consider not asking for the key during the install.  Do it on first run of the application instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) IMO, UI support in Windows Installer is sometimes too weak to implement complicated requirements... Is there some tutorial for writing an external UI? Is it difficult?

Comment: Windows Installer is a declarative framework.  Complicated things can be done,  it's more that it's a restrictive paradigm.

Comment: You don't mention what tool you are using to create your MSI.  InstallShield has some stuff here and so does WiX. I also don't know what programming languages you are comfortable in.   That said, I'd probably look at Windows Installer XML (WiX) and the Burn bootstrapper.  You can create a custom UI here and there are examples of how to do it in managed code / WPF if you'd like also.

Comment: But I caution you, you are wading into the deep end of the pool on a requirement that I wouldn't rate very high in the first place.